# Mailing List on GitHub Pages

Tags: html, forms, github, github-pages

I am currently using Github Pages as a host for my new domain, after I learned that it is free, and that all I needed to purchase was the domain, which I have.

My only problem is that GitHub Pages doesn't support PHP and I want to have a mailing list where users keep their email and I save their email for later contact with clients. This is easily done in PHP but GitHub Pages doesn't support it so I I am in need of an alternative.

Jekyll isn't that helpful. I have also tried a normal `form` in HTML where the action attribute is a `mailto` address, but that also isn't good enough. Any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: GitHub Pages is for **static** content. There's no way you can do what you're asking with Github Pages -- you'll need a proper web host to run PHP, or any other server-side language.

Answer (score 2):

Since github page doesnt support any Backend languages ,you simply cannot use it for mailing purpose !

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a tool like [Mailchimp](https://mailchimp.com/help/add-a-signup-form-to-your-website/). Unfortunately (but with good reason) Github pages don't have access to PHP or any other back-end tools.